# Connectbot menu on Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I just upgraded to Lollipop on my Nexus 5 and I use Connectbot a lot. There used to be a menu button, with things like "URL scan" and "Paste".  But with Lollipop that menu button is replaced with a button where I can change my keyboard. Totally redundant, since there is already a button for that on the keyboard (or at least, there is with Hackers Keyboard).

So the question is, does anyone know how to get the menu button back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press 'back', then the keyboard changer button is replaced by the menu buttom. This is still a bit more complex than what it was in the 4.x times, but should at least allow you to disconnect if you want to avoid e.g. manually detaching your screen, etc.